Convert jQuery to Javascript Read more, read less
I need help with my jQuery code. I was able to make it work for the read more and read less script, but I am unable to make it work on javascript code or vanilla js code. I hope you can help me with my issue.
Below are my code for Jquery that works:
 <div class="short-desc">I am a short description preview</div>
 <div class="full-desc" style="display:none">I am a full version preview</div>

        <a href='#' class='read-more'>View More</a>
        
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( ".read-more" ).on( "click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($(".short-desc").is(':visible')){
                  $(".short-desc").hide();
                  $(".full-desc").show();
                  $(this).text("View less");
                }
                else{
                  $(".short-desc").show();
                  $(".full-desc").hide();
                  $(this).text("View more");              
                }
                
            });
        });
    });     
    </script>

I'm trying to convert the jQuery code to JavaScript or VanillaJS code, but it's not working. Below are the javascript code I make but I can't replicate how the jQuery function work. NOTE: I am adding this to a different div id


    <div id="short-desc">I am short description</div>
        <div id="full-desc" style="display:none">I am full description</div>

        <a href='#' onclick="myFunction()">View More</a>
        
        


<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("full-desc");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

const paragraph = document 
                .getElementById('short-desc'); 
            const currentVisibility = window 
                .getComputedStyle(paragraph).visibility; 
  
            if (currentVisibility === 'hidden') { 
                paragraph.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
            } else { 
                paragraph.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
            }
</script>


"it's not working" isn't particularly helpful. How is it not working as expected? What steps have you taken to debug it?

The jQuery .is(":visible") is not a simple check on the CSS "visibility" style. It is much more complicated than that.

@mykaf the code should be on javascript not jquery, the javascript code is not working like the id short-desc is not showing when you run it, the goal is replicate how the jquery code work into javascript code :-(

@Pointy I dont have issues on the jquery code, the javascript code is the issue :-(

I understand that; what's happening with your javascript that doesn't meet your expectations? Be specific. What steps have you taken to debug it?

@JamezC my point is that your translation of .is(":visible") is very wrong.

@mykaf the "I am short description" with an id short-desc is not showing, the expectation should be when I run the code the "I am short description" should be visible then if I click the "View more" hyperlink should show "I am full description"  then the "View more" should change to "View less" then if click again "view less" the "I am full description"  should be hidden and "I am short description" will be visible again. I was able to make research a working javascript code with read more read less script but the examples are only 1 div that was used. I am using 2 div

the description is showing and hiding as expected when I click the link. Where do you attempt to display "view less" in your JS?

Actually you can do this with so much way.
This is one of many ways
https://jsfiddle.net/mo0svwLn/
const fullDesc = document.querySelector("#full-desc");
const shortDesc = document.querySelector("#short-desc");
const viewMore = document.querySelector("#view-more");

const showFullDesc = () => {
    shortDesc.style.display = "none";
    fullDesc.style.display = "block";

    viewMore.textContent = "View less"
}

const showShortDesc = () => {
    shortDesc.style.display = "block";
    fullDesc.style.display = "none";

    viewMore.textContent = "View more"
}


viewMore.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (fullDesc.style.display == "none") {
        showFullDesc();
    } else if (shortDesc.style.display == "none") {
        showShortDesc();
    }
});


yay!!! THANK YOU SO SOO MUCH! :-)

your welcome... happy coding! :)
